# How to Interpret Confidence Interval ILSR Ch 3 Q10g

Tags: r, multiple-regression, confidence-interval, interpretation

Using the Carseats dataset in R, predicting the Sales of carseats (Unit sales (in thousands)) using price and US (sold in US, not sold in US). How would I interpret the confidence interval in words? Thanks

[image: Summary of Regression Line:]

[image: Confidence Interval:]

Comment: Your two screenshots have different parameter estimates. Also, the CIs you are screenshotting here do not pertain to prediction, but to model fitting.

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain how to think about confidence intervals for model fitting. I'm not really sure what to make of it.

Comment: Have you looked at the duplicate? There is a lot of information about CIs out there. Please be more explicit as to what you do not understand.